# How to use cases inside of where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to choose one of the following paths. The user will either enter the customer name (@customer), the supplier name (@supplier), or the part number (@part). When they enter one of those I want to do a search in my table like customer_name=@customer if they choose customer and the same if they choose any of the others. Here is what I am trying.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_edit_button
(
    @customer nvarchar(200) = NULL,
    @supplier nvarchar(200) = NULL,
    @part nvarchar(100) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM REC_INSP_LOG
    WHERE (
        CASE
            WHEN @customer IS NOT NULL THEN customer_name = @customer
            WHEN @supplier IS NOT NULL THEN supplier_name = @supplier
            WHEN @part IS NOT NULL THEN part_num = @part
        )
END
```

Comment: You should have separate queries for all the cases as the most efficient access paths will be different for all the cases. All three cases can potentially use index seeks (on different indexes) if available. You can  add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to help but then you pay the compilation cost

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that might be easier, didn't know if this way would be more efficient or not. Thanks Martin Smith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can phrase this logic without a `case` expression:

```
WHERE (@customer IS NULL OR customer_name = @customer) AND
      (@supplier IS NULL OR supplier_name = @supplier) AND
      (@part IS NULL OR part_num = @part)
```

That said, the resulting query will not be able to take advantage of any indexes on a table.  If that is something you want, then you will need to use conditional logic or dynamic SQL.

Comment: Would it be better to check the column for null instead and chain everything together with OR's?
`WHERE (customer_name IS NOT NULL AND customer_name = @customer) OR (supplier_name IS NOT NULL AND supplier_name = @supplier) OR (part_num IS NOT NULL AND part_num = @part)`
Should come down to the same result and might be more efficient for the indexes.

Comment: @Gamingdevil . . . That is not the same logic, so it is not better.

Answer (score 0):

That indeed can't work, because you're treading the realm of dynamic SQL. Also note that your `CASE` is supposed to  have an `END` at the end.
I would suggest taking a look at Gordon's answer or, if you're set on using a case, you could try this:

```
(CASE 
    WHEN (@customer IS NOT NULL AND customer_name = @customer)
      OR @supplier IS NOT NULL AND supplier_name = @supplier
      OR @part IS NOT NULL AND part_num = @part THEN 1
    ELSE 0
 END) = 1
```

But you still wouldn't be able to use the index properly.